# Jupyter + EMR + Spark - Connect to EMR cluster from Jupyter notebook on local machine

Tags: python, pyspark, jupyter, amazon-emr

I am new to PySpark and EMR.
I am trying to access Spark running on EMR cluster through Jupyter notebook, but running into errors.

I am generating SparkSession using following code:

```
spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .master("local[*]")\
    .appName("parallelization on Spark")\
    .getOrCreate()
```

Tried following to access Remote cluster, but it errored out:

```
spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .master("spark://<remote-emr-ec2-hostname>:7077")\
    .appName("parallelization on Spark")\
    .getOrCreate()
```

Error:

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling None.org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.
: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:567)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.<init>(JavaSparkContext.scala:58)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
```

Any help resolving this would be much appreciated.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: No @bvmcode, was not able to resolve this.

Answer (score -1):

EMR clusters have Jupyter and JupyterHub provisioned for you [since EMR version 5.14.0](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-jupyterhub.html).

Most likely, it is easier to [tune those provisioned services up](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/running-jupyter-notebook-and-jupyterhub-on-amazon-emr/) with some extra bootstrap actions than to wire up your local process to talk to the EMR master node.